# camel property file not found in class path

Tags: apache-camel, properties-file

I'm trying to read property file from class path.

I have project name - PROG , under it there is a folder named resources and in it there is a property file : myProp

In camel context xml my code is :

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:PROG.resources.myProp" />
```

I tried too :

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:resources.myProp" />
```

but I get camel error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Properties file PROG.resources.myProp not found in classpath
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this XML code to configure a property placeholder:

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:/resources/myProp" />
```

Here's the official example from https://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:com/mycompany/myprop.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Try using a real path, not the "." notation from `ResourceBundle`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well, it's how I do it in my code and how https://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html describes it in section "Configuring in Spring XML".

Comment: you need to give more complete answers if you want them accepted. Try this isnt likely to get you answer tried or accepted.Even if its correct.

Comment: Modified the answer with more details and the example from Camel documentation.